# Why do I lose items that are with the courier when I die in Dota 2?

Tags: dota-2

Hi I recently started playing Dota 2 and I've had an issue with items disappearing when I die. I played 2 games last night and for both games I noticed this occurring.

Basically I will buy items, get my courier to deliver it and before my courier gets to me if I die then when I respawn the items are missing. An example is last night I bought 2 items worth over 2000 gold, sent for the courier, died, and when I respawned my items were missing and the 2000 gold was also missing. The gold is definitely not missing due to the cost of respawning.

Is this meant to happen? I've talked to more experienced players and looked at online material but I can't find anything related. I thought the items should be returned to you when you respawn and that's why quick buying right before dying is useful but this is making that unfeasible. It got to the point where getting items delivered by courier was too risky if it was an expensive item.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I've never heard something like this before, does it happens every time ? If yes could you make a video ? Have you checked the replay to see what exactly happened ?

Comment: If you die while the courier is delivering items to you, the courier will return to base. Then another Hero can use the courier while your dead, meaning that the courier is on the road. When the courier is back in base, you can ask the courier to deliver to you, and you should get your items. (im not 100% sure, but pretty positive that this is how it works)

Comment: Did this happen in multiple different games or only one game? In any case, watching the replay can be useful.

Comment: This is actually a bug that has been reported on the dota2 dev forums. In rare cases, if you die and the courier was delivering the items to you, the items will be dropped off at the place of your death (regardless of where the courier is).

Answer (score 9):

If you die the courier will return to the fountain and wait there (unless someone else gives it an order).
It will still have all your items in its inventory, just tell it to send them to you again when you resurrect.

It is also possible to tell the courier to return the items to your stash (select the courier unit, press the "Return items to stash" button, it will walk to the fountain and return your items) and you can just drag and drop your items into your inventory from your stash.

Answer (score 3):

My first guess is someone (A teamate) took the item from the courrier and drag n dropped them to the ground. "Why ?" you ask, the answer is pretty simple, a lots of DotA players at low levels are Jerks. I advice you check the replay and follow the path of the courrier to see exactly what happened but I'm pretty sure that's the only explanation.

Some piece of advice, if I'm correct and if you want to avoid any future bad surprise like this, try to play with friends. The game can only be better (it could also destroy your friendhsip forever but isn't that the case with any games :D ?)

Comment: Thanks for your help everyone. I didn't realize you could interact with the courier so it's likely the courier did still have my stuff. I'll definitely check that next game. I'll also look at the play back to make sure no one chucked it.

Answer (score 0):

your items should be in the courier after you die, just call it again.